# Why do these folders get created when I create a virtual env for python instead of just a single venv folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, python-venv

Did something change with using `venv`? I tried to use this command to create a virtual env in `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\venv`, but instead it created two folders - `v2` and `Windows` in `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\FOLDER1\FOLDER2`. Why did it do this? Which one of these folders do I use? And why didn't it just put everything into a single `venv` folder like I wanted?

```
 python -m venv C:\Users\USER\Desktop\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\venv
```

[image]

Comment: what happens when you `cd` to folder `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\FOLDER1\FOLDER2` and execute `python -m venv venv`

Comment: @rioV8 it created a `venv` folder and seems to have put the appropriate stuff inside: Include, Lib, Scripts, and pyvenv

Comment: the first parameter to module `venv` is the name of the folder, not the full path of the folder

Comment: @rioV8 I followed the instructions on the venv docs. It said to do `c:\>c:\Python35\python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv`

Comment: Link to docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: if you get different outcome for path (as mentioned in the doc) and name-only you can try to debug the venv module and/or create an issue at the python repo

Comment: I looked at the source code and the first thing it does is create an `abspath` of the given argument, if I write a test script it returns the same `abspath` in both cases, I tried, with Python 3.8 and `FOLDER1\FOLDER2` not existent, to create a venv with `C:\Python\Path\python.exe -m venv c:\Users\XYZZYX\Desktop\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\venv` and it creates a correct virtenv. **What are the actual `FOLDER1` and `FOLDER2` names?** Do you have spaces or other strange characters in it, or in the Username, test yourself if `abspath` is identical in both cases